# Attempting to reference a deleted function (VS2013)

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm trying to write a game of checkers in SDL. When I compile my code, I get this error:

> std::basic_ifstream>::basic_ifstream(conststd::basic_ifstream> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

From what I can find on the web, this means that the compile has helpfully deleted my constructor for some reason, and now it can't find it again. (Bad organization if you ask me) Why could this be?

Board.h:

```
#include <fstream>
class Board
{
public:
    SDL_Surface * boardSurface;
    int boardArray[8][8];
private:
    std::ifstream boardFile;
    SDL_Surface * blackPiece;
    SDL_Surface * whitePiece;
    SDL_Surface * darkSquare;
    SDL_Surface * lightSquare;

public:
    Board(char filename[], SDL_PixelFormat * format);
private:
    void loadFile(char filename[]);
    void makeSurface();
    void debugPrint();
    void debugBlit();
};
```

Board.cpp:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "board.h"
#include "loaders.h"

Board::Board(char filename[], SDL_PixelFormat * format)
{
    //inits images
    loaders imageLoader;
    blackPiece = imageLoader.load_image("images/blackPiece.png", format);
    whitePiece = imageLoader.load_image("images/whitePiece.png", format);
    darkSquare = imageLoader.load_image("images/darkSquare.png", format);
    lightSquare = imageLoader.load_image("images/lightSquare.png", format);
    boardSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 780, 480, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    loadFile(filename);
    debugPrint();
    debugBlit();
}
void Board::loadFile(char filename[])
{
    boardFile.open(filename);
    char currentLine[9] = {};
    for (int line = 0; line <= 7; line++)
    {
        boardFile.getline(currentLine, 9);
        for (int square = 0; square <= 7; square++)
        {
            int currentSquare = (int)currentLine[square] - '0'; 
            boardArray[line][square] = currentSquare;
        }
    }
}

void Board::makeSurface()
{

}

void Board::debugPrint()
{
    for (int line = 0; line <= 7; line++)
    {
        for (int square = 0; square <= 7; square++)
        {
            std::cout << boardArray[line][square];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Board::debugBlit()
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++)
    {
        if (SDL_BlitSurface(blackPiece, NULL, boardSurface, NULL) != 0)
        {
            std::cout << SDL_GetError();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you implement the C++ standard library every other afternoon, the error is not about *your* constructor. Can you identify the class mentioned in that message?

Comment: "This diagnostic occured in the compiler-generated function Board::Board(const Board&)"
It's my board class, I think.

Comment: Where in the code you show does the error occur? I can't copy paste this code and make it work. Or even not work. You're missing loaders.h here. Also, please see http://sscce.org/

Comment: I was copying Board somewhere, yes. I did something else in its place, and the error is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error happens because you have an `std::ifstream` data member, and you are probably trying to copy a `Board` somewhere, or have some code that requires the copy constructor to be accessible.

```
std::ifstream boardFile;
```

The `Board` compiler-provided copy constructor tries to copy the stream, but the stream is not copyable. So you have to either provide your own copy constructor to do something clever, or remove code that requires the `Board` copy constructor.

Comment: Would using a pointer to the ifstream as the class member and allocating/deallocating the ifstream in the class's constructor/destructor be an acceptable solution?