# ofstream in class - attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, string, parameters, char, fstream

- I have seen this question: [Attempting to reference a deleted function (VS2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664164/attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function-vs2013) but it didn't provide me an answer.

I have a member variable in class which its type is `ofstream` and a constructor which contains string parameter:

```
class dogs
{
public:
    ofstream dogsFile;

    dogs(string location)
    {

    }
};
```

The following error appears:

> Error 2   error C2280: 'std::basic_ofstream>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function  c:\users\pc\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\database\database\database.cpp    26  1   Database

I have tried this code again but instead of using string I used char*:

```
class dogs
{
public:
    ofstream dogsFile;

    dogs(char* location)
    {

    }
};
```

And the error disappeared. Why? why does string makes the error?

Edit:
This is the whole code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class dogs
{ 
    ofstream dogsFile;

public:
    dogs(string location)
    {

    }
};

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    dogs dog = dogs("dog.bin");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: C++ streams are non copyable - delete copy constructors and assignment operators (C++11) of your class, or make them private

Comment: Dieter Lücking - it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @OpenGL97 I'm suppose you the error is because a line you havn't posted, right? If so, post it please.

Comment: @OpenGL97 that is most likely the exact reason for your problem

Comment: Raydel Miranda - Actually that's all the code.
 Dieter Lücking - how the diffence between char* and string is connected to the stream that are non copyable? I didn't understand that.

Comment: And what include files are you including?

Comment: @OpenGL97 This code isn't causing a copy anywhere. The only constructor you're invoking on the stream is the default-constructor, and that's it. There has to be more code that you aren't showing us.

Comment: Mark in your code *exactly* where line `database.cpp:26` is. In fact, this seems trivial enough, post a full source with-`main()` that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question. You can see the whole code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original answer by Dieter seems to be correct.
I.e. This will compile:

```
dogs *dog = new dogs("dog.bin");
```

Your line will not, see his answer about copy constructors.

the dogs("dog.bin") will create an object then "=" will make a copy of it and give it to dog. Can't copy  object with ofstream in it.

You can also fix this by using

```
dogs dog("dog.bin");
```

instead.

Comment: Actually, not all of this answer is correct. `dogs("dog.bin")` will create a temporary object, an rvalue, which means that the copy-initialization should actually invoke the implicitly-defined move constructor for the dogs class, which should call the move constructor for std::ofstream, which is actually *defined*. Clang 3.5 actually accepts the code with no errors. It seems to me that it's more of a quirk in VC++, but I'm not entirely sure yet, that's why I didn't post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of this as anything else than a bug in VC++.

The way the `dogs` class is defined, the compiler should generate an implicit move constructor for it, which will call the move constructor for `std::ofstream`, which is [*defined as of C++11*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream).

The rules for when to define an implicit move constructor are specified in the standard in [12.8/9] and [12.8/11]. They're also listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor). I can't see any reason not to declare the implicit move constructor in this case.

Then, the line

```
dogs dog = dogs("dog.bin");
```

must invoke a move from the temporary `dogs` object on the right hand side to the left-hand-side `dog` (the move may be elided, but the constructor needs to be accessible nonetheless).

In short, everything should work fine.

And it does in Clang 3.5. It doesn't work in GCC, but only because it doesn't have move constructors defined for stream classes (it's not standard-compliant in that respect).

Funnily enough, it works in VC++, as the OP duly mentioned, if the `dogs` constructor is declared to take anything else but a `std::string` by value. Change the constructor to any of the following:

```
dogs(const string& location)
```

or

```
dogs(int a) //And change the call accordingly, of course.
```

or

```
dogs(A a) //And change the call accordingly (A is a user-defined class).
```

and everything will work fine in VC++, as it should.

The fact that it doesn't work only for `std::string` passed by value seems to indicate there's a bug in the compiler. Basically, in that case, and only in that case, the compiler decides not to define the implicit move constructor, which causes the copy initialization to fall back to calling the copy constructor, which causes the error.

If you explicitly define the move constructor, like this:

```
dogs(dogs&& arg) : dogsFile(std::move(arg.dogsFile)) { }
```

again, everything works fine, including with the constructor taking a `std::string` by value.

I can't see any valid reason for VC++ to behave this way.